# How can I exclude a "report.specification" from a Report in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect, documentation-generation, data-dictionary

I am attempting to generate a data dictionary for a package, but I cannot figure out how to exclude the report that is my data dictionary.

I get this item:
[image]

in my generated PDF on the last page:
[image]

I have tried Generate Documentation ➜ Exclude Filters ➜ Exclude diagram type and selecting Extended Documentation, Maintenance, and ModelDocument

[image]

And I have also tried Generate Documentation ➜ Exclude Filters ➜ Element Filters and adding a filter where the Name `Not Equals` **Data Dictionary**

[image]

But I still get the "Data Dictionary" page as the last page in my data dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation yet to comment for clarification so I went ahead and tested it on my own

It works for me (On EA Version 13.1308):

[Package setup with the report specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fidvw.png)

[Element Filters set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6J5Q.png)

(I cannot provide more images as I reached my links limit, just take my word for it, the report specification isn't in the final report)

Provide each step you are doing to generate your report

Also, make sure you are not closing the generate Documentation window after setting your filters, as it will remove them

Comment: It does work with Element Filters and my screen shot does produce the correct report.  But I had to exit and re-open so I think there is a bit of a refresh issue when configuring documentation.