# How can I include a clickable (hyperlinks) table of contents when generating documents in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect, documentation-generation, data-dictionary

I have a data dictionary report in Enterprise Architect (same as in this question: [How can I exclude a "report.specification" from a Report in Enterprise Architect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936068/how-can-i-exclude-a-report-specification-from-a-report-in-enterprise-architect)) and I would like a table of contents that is clickable (has links).

The current report does generate bookmarks, but if it is possible, I'd like to have a "live" Table of Contents in the output PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in EA right now
Closest developper response I could get for this issue is [this](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,25731.msg203231.html#msg203231) forum post:

> I talked with Sparx on this topic as I had the same question.
>
> Their response...
>
> "The 3rd party add-in we use for generating these documents does not
>   support the TOC hyperlinking - so unfortunately the only alternative
>   is to open the document in another application like Open Office or
>   Word and simply right-click and update the TOC."

You can always open the Document in Word or Adobe Reader and use the Navigation Pane:
(Word 2013)
 1. Click View on the ribbon
 2. In the show Section, click Navigation Pane

(Acrobat Reader)
Use the Bookmarks Pane

Also, I find that when generated as a .rtf or .pdf report, the Table of Contents generates with the wrong Style, messing with the Navigation Pane.
Generating the Document in Word format solves this issue

Another Solution:

You can generate the report without the table of contents with Word, create the table of contents when generated and then export it to whatever format you need

Edit:
After some digging, I found that in Word, you can update the TOC and then ctrl+click the numbers to jump pages.

You cannot do this with a pdf